# Android Studio AVD configuration issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a new AVD in my newly installed Android Studio. There is one option only no matter what device I select and that is Android L (Preview). With this as the only option to select, I get the following error at the bottom of the wizard:

```
No CPU/ABI system image available for this target.
```

What to do? I want to get this up and running to start development.

Comment: Did you go through the steps? https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Comment: I got it working by going through the SDK manager and getting the different ones I needed.

Comment: This helped me out, too, thanks!  I didn't realize all the different pieces I need to download separately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you **download** the system image from **Android SDK Manager**?

Launch that up in your **eclipse** and you should see all the **android version** 
(**Example: Android 4.4.2 (API 19)**)

**Expand it** and there should contains files like "**Intel x86 Atom System Image**" & "**ARM EABI v7a System Image**".

**Check those and install** them and you should able to launch your emulator with the option to choose between the system image.